# A question about set theory and Frege logic

Tags: lo.logic

Does there exist a very weak axiomatic theory of arithmetic-weaker than (but possibly a sub-theory of)
Robinson's theory Q-which can be interpreted in the first order fragment of Frege logic? If so, what are
the axioms of such a theory? By "the first order fragment of Frege logic" I mean the system discussed on
pages 251-252 of the book "One Hundred years of Russell's Paradox" (edited by Godehard Link).

Comment: I don't have a copy of this book. Is the list of axioms too long to post here?

Comment: How weak will you allow? For example, the empty theory? After all, Q is already extremely weak (the weakest known theory to support the incompleteness theorem). 

Comment: Presburger arithmetic is weaker in some sense than Q, but I don't know if one can interpret Frege's FOL in it. See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4107/what-are-some-examples-of-theories-stronger-than-presburger-arithmetic-but-weaker

Comment: My question is actually the reverse of this. Can one interpret
Presburger Arithmetic in Frege's FOL?
